# Change background color slowly

Tags: javascript

I have this code that works perfectly, when lowering the scrol x pixels the background of my manu changes to the chosen color. But I can't figure out how to make that color not change all at once, but slowly.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var fondo = document.getElementById("fondo")
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    fondo.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";
  } else {
    fondo.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
};
```

Comment: Set a CSS transition or have a function map from scroll position to background color.

Comment: Look into the css property called transition

Comment: See here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition

Answer (score 3):

Don't delay using JS, instead use a CSS transition by toggling a class. For example:

```js
window.onscroll = scrollFunction;

const fondo = document.getElementById("fondo")
function scrollFunction() {
  fondo.classList.toggle(
    'scrolled', 
    document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200
  );
}
```

```css
#fondo {
  transition: background-color 1s;
  background-color: rgba(180, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 700px;
}
#fondo.scrolled {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.upper {
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">upper</div>
<div id="fondo"></div>
```